# PHP Mail submit form without refreshing

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using the plugin [formtomail](http://formtoemail.com) to send emails. The problem that I am experiencing is that I do not want the page to refresh after submitting the form from the template which is called in the action of the form on the primary page. Does someone know how to do this that has worked with this plugin?

Comment: If you dont refresh page you will need use ajax on background because if you send request to the server then you wait for response which is that refresh with new content. Use ajax.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help a little:
first you need to edit the html page that has the form.
then add this script to it and adjust it properly.

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Hussein, after ajax you kept preventDefault(), it should be before var form